# Unable to assign to object property after getting from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this class:

```
public class Product {
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Recommended {get;set;}

    public int ID {get;set;}
    //Other stuff
}
```

Then I get them from the database and assign the Recommended variable. I've set them all to true for now, while I test and that works.

```
var Products = Find(SearchParams, DataContext).ToList();
foreach(var product in Products) {
    product.Recommended = true;
    if (!product.Recommended) throw new Exception();
}
```

Ok, it works, we pass.

Then I go and make a set of results, which look like this:

```
public class QuoteProduct {
    public Product Product {get;set;}
    public Quote Quote {get;set;}
    //etc
}
```

And assign the products:

```
var Results = new List<QuoteProduct>();
foreach(var product in Products) {
    var entry = new QuoteProduct(){
        Product = product;
        Quote = getQuote(this);
    }
    if (!entry.Product.Recommended) throw new Exception();
    Results.add(entry);
}
```

and that exception is always thrown! Why? Even if, just before it I do:

```
    entry.Product.Recommended = true;
    if (!entry.Product.Reccomended) throw new Exception();
```

Comment: What is the exact exception thrown ?

Comment: this one: throw new Exception();

Comment: where is the code for this `getQuote(this)` ?

Comment: I made it up, that's just an example showing there are other things in that class that get assigned to. You can assume it just returns `new Quote();` which has a single property an `int ID`

Comment: are you at working in the same scope?

Comment: It may seem a nonsense but...is your `Recommended` property getter and setters exactly as you have shown us? I mean, maybe are you doing something in your getter/setter that could interfere with setting the property to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lazy evaluation problem**

`Find(SearchParams, DataContext);` is probably returning an `IEnumerable<>` so each time you iterate it, new `Product` classes are generated. This makes the `product.Recommended = true;` useless.

---

*Here:*

```
var Products = Find(SearchParams, DataContext);
foreach(var product in Products)    // <--- here it's iterated and new classes instantiated
{
    product.Recommended = true;
    if (!product.Recommended) throw new Exception();
}
```

*and here:*

```
var Results = new List<QuoteProduct>();
foreach(var product in Products)   // <-- and here are new classes instantiated
// So your previous `product.Recommended = true;` is gone!
{
    var entry = new QuoteProduct(){
        Product = product;
        Quote = getQuote(this);
    }
    if (!entry.Product.Recommended) throw new Exception();
    Results.add(entry);
}
```

---

**You can fix it with:**

```
// The key is to persist the data with (for example) ToArray() or ToList()
var Products = Find(SearchParams, DataContext).ToArray();
```

The downside of persisting is, that ALL 'rows' are loaded simultaneous into the memory. *(that's why the lazy evaluation is usefull)*

Comment: Yeah, I tried `foreach(var product in Products.ToList()) {` didn't seem to work.

Comment: The point where you store the `var Products` needs to be iterated ones (so a `ToList()` of a `ToArray()` will solve that.

Comment: You might read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2007/06/02/lazy-evaluation-in-c/

Comment: The key is to persist the items before iterating.

Comment: No, I've added ToList() but it still hasn't worked. I think it's because the Product that is assigned is a normal product (`{bitmedia.vendors.Product}`), but the product in entry is a `{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_63330855CF6DCD552168A7CC2FFE449304533EEE25346379EFE7906FAD68924B}` but I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you update the code where you added the `ToList()`?

Comment: Updated. Exactly where you said to add it, which is why I'm so puzzled. I'm even assigning right before I do the check and it still thows the exception. I can even debug line by line, see it pass the assignment and there was no change, but no exception thrown to say the assignment failed.

Comment: `/// <summary>
        /// This is set based on the sales channel and so will be false until you run SalesChannel.IsProductRecommended()
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public bool Recommended { get; set; }`

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out. It was the get and the set on the quote product, it was overloaded with a function to load it from the database using a old stored procedure.

Comment: Please can you test your code again without my fix? And share the results?

Comment: @Pikoh I... um... Yes? I'm grateful for everyone's help giving up their time to help solve my coding issues, whether it solves my problem or not.

@ Jeroen van Langen yeah, without ToList() it doesn't work.